# How to suppress constraint layout error "MATCH_PARENT is not supported in ConstraintLayout"

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

On the newest version of constraint layout, Beta 5, using match_parent throws an exception:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: MATCH_PARENT is not supported in ConstraintLayout
```

As explained in the release note:

> "(...) its behavior undefined. To reduce the risk of errors we now throws an
>   exception if we encounter it." - [source](https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/recent/constraintlayoutbeta5isnowavailable)

They suggested that the correct usage would be to use 0dp (MATCH_CONSTRAINT), but since I have a Drawer Layout inside my constraint layout, setting the width to 0dp throws "DrawerLayout must be measured with MeasureSpec.EXACTLY" error.

So my question is how can I suppress the error "MATCH_PARENT is not supported in ConstraintLayout"?

Comment: You can't.  Even if you found a way to do it, it probably wouldn't work.  And its not promised to work on all versions of the library.  You just aren't supposed to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least as of version 1.1.0-beta3 of the constraint layout,

**You can use match_parent without issues.**

However it's still recommended that you use:

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
```

Comment: It's worth noting that the performance hit when using match_parent can be very high - I had a layout where I used match_parent for element in view pager and it hardly worked on slightly slower devices (like it would take seconds to scroll) - changing to 0dp and constraining to left/right parent solved this issue

Answer (score 12):

The replacement of

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

in a ConstraintLayout can be done with

```
android:layout_width="0dp" 
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
```

i.e. constraining the widget to the right and left edges of the parent

Comment: I had already tried this, but since I have a DrawerLayout inside my ConstraintLayout I received the "DrawerLayout must be measured with MeasureSpec.EXACTLY" error, as mentioned in my question. I ended up using a LinearLayout.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, nice to know